# Why would multiple process launched from the same .exe be faster when launched from different copies of the .exe in windows

Tags: performance, windows-server-2012, resources

I am seeing some strange application behavior on some win 2012 servers.

A service launches up to  8 instances of someApp.exe. as the process terminates the service launches another so there are always about 7 or 8 running.

They are running very slow (4 mins vs ~3 seconds per process) as of about a month ago. I am told "nothing has changed".

If I launch this from the console it is also slow,

BUT if I make a copy in a new directory and launch it there it is fast.
If I call the original from a different directory it is slow.

I've cleaned up temporary files, and working directories.

My current theory is that there must be some resource the windows controls per exe, and not per process.

Does anyone know how to explain or fix this?

Comment: Check memory consumtion and cache. Sounds like the executable is not cached and thus not accessed from memory but from disk instead. Given its the same disk, it may wait on certain read/write handles, where a copy would have its own read/write handle without queue and thus can work much faster.

Comment: It may be that the executable builds up something in its folder that slows it down, so a new folder gets rid of it. Compare a new with old folders to see what has changed.